# How to share global Map values among RDDs in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to access a Map from RDDs than are on different compute nodes, but without success. The Map is like:

```
val map1 = Map("aa"->1,"bb->2,"cc->3,...)
```

All RDDs will have to check against it to see if the key is in the Map or not, so seems I have to make the Map itself global, the problem is that if the Map is stored as RDDs and spread across the different nodes, each node will only see a piece of the Map and the info will not be complete to check against the Map( an then replace the key with the corresponding value) E,g:

```
val matchs= Vecs.map(term=>term.map{case (a,b)=>(map1(a),b)})
```

Any idea about this? Thanks!

Comment: Truth be told I am not sure if I understand what you want but you cannot access RDD from a transformation or action on another RDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you simply want to use a broadcast variable:

```
val broadCastMap = sc.broadcast(map)
Vec.map(term=>term.map{case (a,b)=>(broadCastMap.value(a),b)})
```